ebpf how to check the syscalls available
I am looking at an eBPF sample code it has this
SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_tcp_connect")
Now how does one know such a call exists?
I tried following

bpftrace -l & list all kprobes

list all events under this folder
/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls

grep the kernel source code
4.look in
/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl


I do not see it
In general how would one go about looking for such syscalls for use with eBPF

You can get the symbol names for the kprobe function via:

sudo bpftrace -l kprobe:*<keyword>*
sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep <keyword> |grep T

If you don't see it, it means you should use another name in the SEC or when attaching the kprobe function:
$ sudo bpftrace -l kprobe:*tcp_connect
kprobe:tcp_connect
$ sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep tcp_connect |grep T
ffffffff8e9e47f0 T tcp_connect


SEC("kprobe/tcp_connect")


Ah ok
Cool Thx mozillazg
